# Хочу создать свой тип данных в oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, типы, oracle12c

Хочу создать свой "супертип", сижу на 12 версии оракла, но походе что то не понимаю

Тип - схема робота(чертёж)
Объект - робот

У робота будут следующие свойства:

- модель процессора
- имя
- вес

Робот должен уметь:

- ходить(когда вызываем эту команду, в консоль должно вывестись "Робот (имя) пошёл")
- говорить(когда вызываем эту команду, робот должен вывести в консоль все свои характеристики)

После выполнения команд выходит ошибка "pls 905 sv_va_robot_t", что строка (sv_va_robot_t('Игорь', 'pentium g4560', '87 тонны') invalid или "pls 905 robot_h", что r robot_h := robot_h(null,null,null) invalid. Хотя я делаю все по учебнику С. Фейерштейн ст 919 и ст 921, подскажите, что я делаю не так

```
DROP TYPE robot_t FORCE;
DROP TYPE sv_va_robot_t FORCE;
 
CREATE TYPE robot_t AS OBJECT (
  name VARCHAR2 (100) /*
, model_proc VARCHAR2 (100)
, ves VARCHAR2 (100)*/
, MEMBER FUNCTION to_string
       RETURN VARCHAR2
) NOT FINAL;
/
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE BODY robot_t
is
  MEMBER FUNCTION to_string RETURN VARCHAR2
  is
  begin
    RETURN 'Робот '|| self.name || ' идет';
  end;
end;
/
CREATE TYPE sv_va_robot_t UNDER robot_t (
  name VARCHAR2 (100)
, model_proc VARCHAR2 (100)
, ves VARCHAR2 (100)
, OVERRIDING MEMBER FUNCTION to_string RETURN VARCHAR2
);
/
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE BODY sv_va_robot_t
IS
  OVERRIDING MEMBER FUNCTION to_string RETURN VARCHAR2
  IS
  BEGIN
    RETURN 'Робот говорит, что у него есть имя - '
 || self.name 
 || ' модель процессора - '
 || self.model_proc
 || ' вес - '
 || self.ves
 || (SELF as robot_t).to_string;
 END;
END;
/
declare
type shema_robota is table of robot_t;
shema shema_robota := shema_robota ( robot_t ('Жора')
                                   , sv_va_robot_t('Игорь', 'pentium g4560', '87 тонны') );
begin
  for x in 1..shema.count
    loop
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (RPAD ('=', 60, '='));
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (shema (x).to_string);
 END LOOP;
END;
/
```

```
create or replace type robot_h as object (
  name varchar(100)
, mod_proc varchar(100)
, ves varchar(100)
, member function setname(name varchar(100)) return robot_h
, member function setmod_proc(mod_proc varchar(100)) return robot_h
, member function setves(ves varchar(100)) return robot_h);
/
declare
  r robot_h := robot_h(null,null,null);
begin
  c := c.setname('Игорь').setmod_proc('pentium g4560').setves('87 тонны');
end;
/
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ошибка в том, что нельзя в унаследованом типе переопределить атрибут ([пример из вопроса на db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=4eda95bd4082365201f77253c754d5c8)).

Сделайте так:

```
create or replace type baseRobotType force as object (
    name varchar2 (16), member function say return varchar2
) not final not instantiable
/
create or replace type RobotType under baseRobotType (
    proc varchar2 (16), weight number, 
    overriding member function say return varchar2
) final 
/
create or replace type body RobotType is
    overriding member function say return varchar2 is
    begin
        return 'Робот '||self.name||
               ' говорит, что у него '||self.proc||' и он весит '||self.weight;
    end;
end;
/

exec dbms_output.put_line (RobotType ('Жора', 'ARM', 123.5).say);
```

> Робот Жора говорит, что у него: ARM и он весит 123,5

Comment: Огромное спасибо, осталось понять, как работает)